# Grimy planet-wide megacity with elite living on top of a giant rectangular prism

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a picture, from a sci fi movie or book, which I saw a few months ago. The picture had a planet-wide megacity, very dense and grimy, and there was a small elevated platform atop which there was all this beautiful vegetation, water, large estates. The idea was the rulers of the planet lived on top of this giant rectangular prism while everyone else was stuck in the overpopulated megacity below. The rectangular prism had a spectacular waterfall from the beautiful landscape on top to the grimy city below.

Can anyone help me find where I got this image from? I know it was from some well-known book or movie.

If I'm not mistaken, it was from a recent movie — could be wrong though.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SciFi.SE. Can you please take a look at [this list](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335) and [edit] in any extra details you remember?

Comment: "Pop Squad" from Love, Death and Robots vol 2 had an elite class that lived in skyscrapers, but I don't recall any clear image of a massive rectangular prism with estates.

Comment: The first season of *Altered Carbon* had superscrapers the Meths lived in that projected far above the clouds that everyone else lived under.  They had gardens, fountains, etc. but no waterfalls, and there wasn't just one of them.

Comment: @Harabeck Pop Squad was also the first thing I thought of, but I can't find a matching picture